# Multiply after groupby

Tags: pandas

Below is `groupby` and `sum` related values. What's right syntax for **multiply** the related values?

```
df=pd.DataFrame({"Date":['20200603','20200603','20200603','20200604','20200604','20200604'],"shop":[1,1,2,2,3,3],"value":[1,1,1,1,1,1]})
df['Date']=pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])
df.groupby(["Date","shop"]).agg(sum_value=("value",sum))
```

Comment: Can you add expected output?

Answer (score 2):

```
df.groupby(["Date","shop"]).agg(mult_value=("value",np.prod))
```

Comment: just for the curious ones: timings for `np.prod` and `'prod'` are identical

Answer (score 2):

I got you, need [`Series.prod`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.prod.html):

```
df.groupby(["Date", "shop"]).agg(mult_value=("value", "prod"))
```